# Android scroll over whole layout that has listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am trying to figure out how to setup a layout like this:

[image: Layout]

Basically I want to achieve that as the user scrolls he scrolls over whole layout not only in listview, which should consist of comments. As far as I know including `ListView` inside `ScrollView` is not recommended. Also maybe in future I would like to include `MapView` or `MapFragment` between `ListView` and some text.  So how can I achieve this kind of layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add only a ListView, and put the "title" and "some text" in a Header.
Here is how you can implement it:
For the header, you should create a layout: for example called header:`

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="title"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/some_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text"
               />
        </LinearLayout>
```

`

and in your activity you should declare the header:
`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);`

and:

```
ListView yourListView;
 yourListView.addHeaderView(carouselBlock);
```

and you should be carefull to add the header before setting the adapter of the list.

Answer (score 0):

According to Guy Romain (one of Android's key developers), the answer is to use a `LinearLayout` instead of a `Listview`. You can see his reasoning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#comment3653232_3496042).